# Can anyone see a fault in the logic of these two algorithms?

Tags: python

I'm trying to work out what the logical fault between these two algorithms is and I can't seem to crack it, does anyone have an idea? Both the programs execute and get the correct answer but I can't work out what the logical error is.

```
data = [["Jacob", "91"], ["John", "81"], ["James", "71"], ["Joe", "61"]]
name = "Joe"
not_found = True
index = 0
marks = 0

# algorithm A
while not_found:
    if data[index][0] == name:
        marks = data[index][1]
        not_found = False
    index = index + 1
print(marks)

# algorithm B
for i in range(len(data)):
    if name == data[i][0]:
        marks = data[i][1]
print(marks)
```

Comment: _"Both the programs execute and get the correct answer"_ - then why do you think there _is_ a logical error? What are they _supposed_ to be doing?

Comment: To give some more context, this is part of an exercise I've been given, apparently "A logical error is an error in the way a program works. The program can run but does not do what it is expected to do."

The issue I'm having is that the program is so simple that its hard to gauge what the logical error is, if it was an algorithm that was calculating age parameters with incorrect operators it would be easy to spot.

Comment: Algorithm A will raise an 'IndexError' exception if "Joe" is not found in the `data` list but will otherwise terminate immediately once found. Algorithm B will not terminate immediately if "Joe" is found (it will always loop through all the names) but will not otherwise loop indefinitely if "Joe" is not present. Both algorithms therefore are not quite perfect.  But if you assume that the name being sought is always present in `data`, then Algorithm A would terminate sooner.

Comment: Thanks, Booboo for the in-depth explanation I really appreciate it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for "logical" errors in the algorithm, algorithm A has one.

```py
while not_found:
```

If the name doesn't exist in the array, you'll get an index error. It should be

```py
while not_found and index < len(data):
```